# Using $addToSet and upsert in java for an embedded document having specific JSON

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

The query that I want to be executed in MongoDB is as follows

```
db.idx.update({"keyword":"Some dynamic keyword"},
              {$addToSet:{url: "Some dynamic url"}},
              {upsert: True})
```

I need the java equivalent of this MongoDB query, I have tried a lot but I keep on getting errors. I am new to both Java and MongoDB but I'm eager to learn, so, please help me out! And also if you can then explain me the JSON for this query and it's structure. Thanks a million in advance :D (Y)

EDIT :-

What I have tried :-

```
    client = new MongoClient("localhost");
    db = client.getDB("idx");
    BasicDBObject lurl = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject lurl2 = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject lkey = new BasicDBObject();
    for(Element e : links){
        DBCollection colls = db.getCollection(e.text());
        lurl.put("$addToSet", e.attr("href"));
        lurl2.put("url", new BasicDBObject(lurl));
        lkey.put("keyword", e.text());
        colls.update(lkey, lurl2, true, false);
    }
```

The errors that I receive are :-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document field names   can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$addToSet')
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.validateKey(DBCollection.java:1829)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkKeys(DBCollection.java:1787)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkValue(DBCollection.java:1810)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkKeys(DBCollection.java:1788)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkObject(DBCollection.java:1774)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:250)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:191)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:224)
at myse.MySE.extractLinkData(MySE.java:55)
at myse.MySE.crawl(MySE.java:61)
at myse.MySE.main(MySE.java:69)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)

Comment: You should provide a code example and errors you're receiving to show your effort so far.

Comment: @ChristianP I have added my code and the exceptions that I get when I run the program. Please have a look into it (Y)

Comment: I think you're building the query wrong. Put `"$addToSet"` in lurl2 and `"url"` in `lurl`.

Comment: @ChristianP Could you please write the code? I'm still confused...

Comment: It's to long for a comment so I will write is as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your update parameter is wrong (`lurl2`):

```
    lurl.put("url", e.attr("href"));
    lurl2.put("$addToSet", new BasicDBObject(lurl));
```

Comment: The exceptions are gone but I don't see any updates in my db, why is that?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons. You should start by debugging your code and checking which parameters are you sending to your update query.

Comment: The mistake was on my part! I gave the wrong collection name. The name of my collection is "idx" and i specified it as e.text()